# Installing Spring Boot Applications

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot

I installed the spring Boot Application as described in 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html

After installation,

> service {myApp} start

does not work at all.

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
> org / springframework / boot / loader / JarLauncher: Unsupported
> major.minor version 52.0
```

In making this exception, I checked all the environment variables and confirmed that everything was normal. The spring application registered as a service did not work and

> /etc/init.d/{myApp} start

found a normal operation while searching for other methods. I do not know at all whether I can not run as a service because I do not have enough points. Please let me know if you know anyone.

Comment: Your java version on the server is too low.

Comment: I have the similar issue, If I use `service {myApp} start`, I got the same error message, but If I use `/etc/init.d/{myApp} start`, then it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

You compiled your application with java 8 so you need to run it using at least a java **8** version (major.minor version **52.0**) , but you are using a previous JVM version.

You can check the actual version with the command:

```
java -version
```

And here are the references to all versions:

- Java SE 10 = 54
- Java SE 9 = 53
- Java SE 8 = 52
- Java SE 7 = 51
- Java SE 6.0 = 50
- Java SE 5.0 = 49
- JDK 1.4 = 48
- JDK 1.3 = 47
- JDK 1.2 = 46
- JDK 1.1 = 45

Comment: It was not a problem with java version, but the problem was that JDK was not installed in the global. After JAVA PATH is installed globally, it works normally.